# What's in your file?

Tags: c++, c++11, file, io

Another more simple project from my CS1 class that I didn't upload while I was sick last week:

> Write a program that computes all of the following statistics for a
>   file and outputs the statistics to both the screen and to another
>   file: the total number of occurrences of characters in the file, the
>   total number of non-whitespace characters in the file, and the total
>   number of occurrences of letters in the file.

I must use at least two functions in this project. In addition, I am also supposed to count and output the number of occurrences of each character.

**`fileStats.cpp`**:

```
/**
 * @file fileStats.cpp
 * @brief
 * @author syb0rg
 * @date 10/23/14
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

constexpr int ARRAY_LENGTH = 128;

struct Data
{
    size_t total = 0;
    size_t nonWhite = 0;
    size_t letters = 0;
    size_t charCount[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {0};
};

std::string constructString(Data data)
{
    std::stringstream sstm;
    sstm << "Number of characters: " << data.total << "\n";
    sstm << "Number of non-whitespace characters: " << data.nonWhite << "\n";
    sstm << "Number of letters: " << data.letters << "\n" << "\n";

    sstm << "Occurances of each character: " << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        if(data.charCount[i]) sstm << (char) i << ": " << data.charCount[i] << "\n";
    }
    return sstm.str();
}

void outputToFile(std::string fileName, std::string str)
{
    std::ofstream out(fileName);
    out << str;
    out.close();
}

int main()
{
    Data data;    
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");
    char input = '\0';

    while ((input = file.get()) && file.good())
    {
        data.total++;
        data.charCount[input]++;
        if(!isblank(input)) data.nonWhite++;
        if(isalpha(input)) data.letters++;
    }
    file.close();

    std::string result = constructString(data);
    outputToFile("output.txt", result);
    std::cout << result;
}
```

Comment: Too small: `ARRAY_LENGTH = 128;`. Otherwise you need to validate that your character is in the correct range.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a TV show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop over a file character by character.

```
std::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
              [](char c)
              {
                   // DO Stuff
              });
```

Notice: `std::istreambuf_iterator` rather than `std::istream_iterator` to prevent white space being skipped.

Why are you treating a file output differently to output to std::cout?

```
outputToFile("output.txt", result);
std::cout << result;

// Why not.

std::ofstream file("output.txt");
file      << result;
std::cout << result;
```

Also its not as if the output is huge and needs buffering in a string. Just ouput the data object.

```
std::ofstream file("output.txt");
file      << data;
std::cout << data;
```

Answer (score 8):

- You can pass `data` by `const&` as it's not being modified.
- `ARRAY_LENGTH` should probably be an unsigned type, such as `std::size_t`.
- Just to stay safe, terminate the program if the file cannot be opened:

  ```
  if (!file)
  {
      std::cerr << "file cannot be opened";
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  ```
- [You do not really need to call `close()` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748014/do-i-need-to-manually-close-a-ifstream).  It would only be necessary for checking for errors, otherwise the destructor will do this for you.  It shouldn't leak any resources.

Answer (score 7):

- Using `isblank` is a grey area: in C locale you'd be counting newlines as non-whitespace. I think testing for `isspace` is more in line with the assignment.
- The `while` loop in main deserves its own function (which in turn feels like a method of `Data`).
- It feels that `constructString` is really a method of `Data` (e.g. `Data::toString()`).
- Shouldn't `isblank` and `isalpha` be quialified as `std::`?

Answer (score 6):

You use C++-style input/output, but your design is fundamentally C.

An idiomatic C++ solution would have a smart class rather than a dumb struct.  Something like

```
class FileStats {
  public:
    FileStats();

    /* Called once for each character in the file */
    void seen(char c);

    /* Retrieve the statistics */
    unsigned int getTotal();
    unsigned int getNonWhite();
    unsigned int getCount(char c);
};
```

Comment: Boo. Getters. Boo. Breaks encapsulation. Write an output operator instead.

Comment: @LokiAstari If you want the reporting format to be a fixed template, sure. That hurts reusability, in my opinion.

Comment: @200_success Somewhat esoteric, maybe for a larger program, or a library, but everything does not have to go in class just because it is C++, it is fine to use C style code with STL if its something small.

Answer (score 5):

Small point.

**This could be written more simply:**

```
while ((input = file.get()) && file.good())
{
    // ...
}
file.close();
```

**as:**

```
while(file.get(input))
{
    // ...
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Why remove the `file.good() ` check?

Comment: @syb0rg `file.get()` returns the input stream which is then converted to a `bool` which is tested by the loop. It pretty much checks the same error flags as `file.good()`. [See Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee that `input` will match up within the range of `ARRAY_LENGTH` depending on what is coming from `stdin`, and from a standard perspective the data may also be up to further interpretation (again depending on what is coming from `stdin`, you could be working on a system which stores data in  a binary format in a hex file in all situations, and you should to be able to account for that, although maybe not to such a ridiculas extend, especially in this program, just keep it in mind and don't assume it will be ASCII), I also think you should do an explicit cast to make the code more clear, overall I would critique your use of `data.charCount[input]++;` and would suggest the use of an `std::map` or setting up the array before hand, then doing this with a bounds check, and seeing if `input` holds a valid charterer.